# A possibly easy question about latent geometry in Collatz sequences

Tags: collatz-conjecture, discrete-dynamical-systems

I have a question about some (seemingly unimportant) behavior I noticed in Collatz sequences, which I haven't been able to find a general answer to upon rough scan of the literature (please be aware that this is not my field, so there may be some ignorance here).

A length-$m$ Collatz tuple is an $m$-tuple of the form $(c_0, c_1, \dotsc, c_{m - 1})$, where $c_0 \in \mathbb N$ and $c_{i + 1}$ is the Collatz iterate of $c_i$ for all $i$.

It appears that all length $m$ Collatz tuples lie on one of $m$ distinct lines in $m$-dimensional space, where the angle between each pair of such lines is $\pi/4$.  This fact is clear for $m=2$, where all length-2 Collatz tuples lie on the lines $y = 3x+1$ and $y = x/2$ which have an intersection angle of $\pi/4$.

That this necessarily holds for the general $m$ case however is not immediately obvious to me (where we take Collatz orbits of length greater than or equal to $m$).  I have been able to come up with a variety of arguments for why this may be the case, but none have been entirely convincing or neat.  Can someone elucidate why this appears to be so, and if this property fails for some $m$, why?  Can you provide sketch of proof (unless I am missing something basic)?

Comment: I think that your definition of a Collatz $m$-tuple can be much simplified, and I made an edit to that effect.  Please feel free to revert if you don't like it (in which case I apologise).  What are the lines for $m = 3$?

Comment: @LSpice you are right, thank you for the edit.  I will also edit the question for the m=3 lines

Comment: Did you mean each pair of neighbouring/successive lines?  I.e. $c_0,c_5$ don't necessarily have $\pi/4$ between them?

Comment: @samerivertwice yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the following arithmetical background of your conjecture.

Put $\Lambda=\{1/2,3\}^m$. For each $\lambda=(\lambda_0,\dots,\lambda_{m-1})\in\Lambda$ we define a vector $r'_\lambda=(r_{\lambda,0},\dots, r_{\lambda,m-1})$ as follows. Put $I(\lambda)=\{0\le i\le m-1:\lambda_i=3\}$. If $I(\lambda)$ is empty then put $r'(\lambda)=0$, otherwise put $i=\min I(\lambda)$, $r'_{\lambda,k}=0$ for $k<i$, $r'_{\lambda,i}=1$, and for each $i+1\le k\le m-1$ let $r'_{\lambda,k}$ equals to $r'_{\lambda,k}/2$, if $\lambda_k=1/2$, and equals to $3r'_{\lambda,k}+1$, if $\lambda_k=3$.

It is easy to see that for each Collatz $m$-tuple $c=(c_0,\dots,c_{m-1})$ there exists $\lambda\in\Lambda$ such that $c=\lambda c_0+ r’_\lambda$.  That is $c$ belongs to a line $r’_\lambda+\lambda t$, $t\in\Bbb R$. It can be well-known for which $\lambda\in\Lambda$ there exists a Collatz $m$-tuple $c=(c_0,\dots,c_{m-1})$ such that $c=\lambda c_0+ r’_\lambda$. The set of all such $\lambda$ provides a family $L$ of lines, containing all Collatz $m$-tuples. Moreover, if a line $\ell’$ in $\Bbb R^m$ contains at least $2^m+1$ Collatz $m$-tuples then $\ell’$ has two common points with some line $\ell\in L$, so $\ell’=\ell$.

Answer (score 0):

The conjecture is false for any possible interpretation, generalization, and/or restriction imposed on the $c_i$. I prove the negation of the conjecture in the following cases in order of the difficulty of their proof (and not generality, if ordered in that fashion we have Case#1 $\subset$ Case#3 $\subset$ Case#2)

1. The $c_i$ form an actual Collatz sequence, *i.e.* $c_m = 1$ and the $c_i \in \mathbb{N}$
2. The $c_i \in \mathbb{Q}$ (the sequences $s_i$ below allow us to consider this generalization of the problem)
3. The $c_i \in \mathbb{N}$ which is the perhaps most meaningful of the cases, this is the case where you take any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and apply the Collatz map $m$ times

**The case that the original poster asked about is Case #3. The counterexamples for Case #2 and Case #3 are optimal in the sense that they are the first $m$ that provides a counterexample. The first counterexample for Case #2 occurs at $m=3$ (*i.e.* in $\mathbb{R}^3$) and the first counterexample for Case #3 occurs at $m= 4$ (*i.e.* in $\mathbb{R}^4$).** The optimal counterexample for Case #1 is $m=2$ (*i.e.* in $\mathbb{R}^2$); this is trivial to prove. In other words

1. Case #1 becomes false at $m=2$ or in $\mathbb{R}^2$
2. Case #2 becomes false at $m=3$ or in $\mathbb{R}^3$
3. Case #3 becomes false at $m=4$ or in $\mathbb{R}^4$

The reason I instead considered $m=7$ first is that I wanted to get some intuition (for big $m$) before attacking the main problem. **Therefore if you just want to get to the negation of the main conjecture skip to Case #3 at the end.** However, if you want some intuition then I posted the solution in the order of the thoughts that occurred to me (i.e. a more natural progression) so that you can go "along for the ride" I went on to prove the negation.

> **Definition** the sequence $s_i$

If we let $f_0 = \frac{n}{2}$ and let $f_1 = 3n+1$ then any such sequence can be encoded as a sequence $(n,s_1,...,s_m)$ where \begin{equation} s_i = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } c_i = f_{0}(c_{i-1})\\ 1 & \text{if } c_i = f_{1}(c_{i-1})  \end{cases} . \end{equation} Your "Collatz vectors" take the form $(n , ...,n_j/2,...., 3n_i +1 ,...., 1)$ where $(c_0,...,c_m)$ is an intial segment of $(n,...,1)$ if $(n,...,1)$ is longer than or equal to $m+1$.

> **Case #1** $c_i \in \mathbb{N}$ and $c_m =1 $

Lets try out $m =7$. Then we have 64 possibilities for the sequences $(n,s_1,...,s_6)$

- 1. $(n,0,0,0,0,0,0)$
- 2. $(n,0,0,0,0,0,1)$

  $\vdots$
- 63. $(n,1,1,1,1,1,0)$
- 64. $(n,1,1,1,1,1,1)$

but we can't end in a $3n+1$ and we can't have $2N_1 \log_2 n > 3 N_0  $ (where $N_0$ is the # of $0$'s and $N_1$ the # of $1$'s), since it must end at 1 (i.e. we must have $3^{N_1}2^{-N_0}n \approx 1 $) therefore actually we only have at most 2 1's for

- 1. $(n,0,0,0,0,0,0)$
- 2. $(n,0,0,0,0,1,0)$
- 3. $(n,0,0,0,1,0,0)$
- $\ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \vdots$
- 6. $(n,1,0,0,0,0,0)$
- 7. $(n,0,0,0,1,1,0)$
- 8. $(n,0,0,1,0,1,0)$
- 9. $(n,0,0,1,1,0,0)$
- 10. $(n,0,1,0,0,1,0)$
- $\ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \vdots$
- 16. $(n,1,1,0,0,0,0)$

Where for example sequence #8 has solution only if the polynomial 
$\frac{1}{2}(3(\frac{1}{2}(3(\frac{x}{4})+1))+1)-1$ has an integer solution *(but not iff however)* which can only produce the following Collatz vectors

- 1. $(64,32,16,8,4,2,1)$
- 2. no solution
- 3. no solution because $(8,4,2,1,4,2,1)$ is not a Collatz sequence
- 4. no solution
- 5. $(10,5,16,8,4,2,1)$
- 6. no solution
- 7. no solution
- 8. no solution
- $\ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \vdots$
- 16. no solution

[I wrote the following code in Haskell (now up on GitHub) to test all of these sequences.](https://github.com/pedrpan/Collatz-sequence)

**Since there are only 2 solutions possible for $m=7$ you can only consider Collatz sequences that don't end in 1, *i.e.* $c_m = 1$, or else your conjecture is false. Therefore we now consider the general case $c_i  \in \mathbb{Q}$.**

> **Case #2** $c_i \in \mathbb{Q}$

Let's try out $m=3$ then the set of lines must be defined by the following sequences $(n,s_1,s_2)$

- 1. $(n,0,0)$
- 2. $(n,0,1)$
- 3. $(n,1,0)$
- 4. $(n,1,1)$

which correspond respectively to the following Collatz vectors $(c_0,c_1,c_2)$

- 1. $(n,\frac{n}{2},\frac{n}{4}) = n(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4})$
- 2. $(n,\frac{n}{2},\frac{3n}{2}+1)$
- 3. $(n,3n+1,\frac{3n+1}{2})$
- 4. $(n,3n+1,9n+3)$

Where the first 3 vectors are linearly independent whenever $n(25^2 + 30n +8) \neq 0$, the last three are linearly independent whenever $n(15^2 + 11n +2) \neq 0$, vectors 1,3, and 4 are linearly independent whenever $n(15^2 + 11n +2) \neq 0$, and vectors 1,2, and 4 are linearly independent whenever $n(25^2 + 30n +8) \neq 0$, which are all simultaneously true for large enough $n$. **Therefore they cannot lie on $m=3$ lines. Therefore the general case for $c_i  \in \mathbb{Q}$ is false. Therefore we now consider the case $c_i  \in \mathbb{N}$.**

> **Case #3** $c_i \in \mathbb{N}$ no restriction on $c_i$

Let's try out $m=4$ then the set of lines must be defined by (a subset of) the following sequences $(n,s_1,s_2,s_3)$

- 1. $(n,0,0,0)$
- 2. $(n,0,0,1)$
- 3. $(n,0,1,0)$
- 4. $(n,0,1,1)$
- 5. $(n,1,0,0)$
- 6. $(n,1,0,1)$
- 7. $(n,1,1,0)$
- 8. $(n,1,1,1)$

however, two $1's$ can't happen back to back and therefore the only possibilities are

- 1. $(n,0,0,0)$
- 2. $(n,0,0,1)$
- 3. $(n,0,1,0)$
- 4. $(n,1,0,0)$
- 5. $(n,1,0,1)$

which correspond respectively to the following Collatz vectors $(c_0,c_1,c_2,c_3)$

- 1. $(n,\frac{n}{2},\frac{n}{4},\frac{n}{8}) $ which happens when $n$ is a power of 2
- 2. $(n,\frac{n}{2},\frac{n}{4},3\frac{n}{4}+1) $ which happens when $n = 4(2k+1)$
- 3. $(n,\frac{n}{2},3\frac{n}{2}+1,\frac{1}{2}(3\frac{n}{4}+1)) $ which happens when $n = 2(2k+1)$
- 4. $(n,3n+1,\frac{1}{2}(3n +1),\frac{1}{4}(3n +1)) $ which happens when $3n+1 = 4k$ or in other words $n = \frac{1}{3}(4k-1)$ which has infinitely many solutions
- 5. $(n,3n+1,\frac{1}{2}(3n +1),\frac{3}{2}(3n +1)+1) $  which happens when $3n+1 = 2(2k+1)$ which also has infinitely many solutions

The first four vectors are linearly independent whenever $ n (5 n + 2) (5 n + 4) (5 n + 8) \neq 0$, the last four vectors are linearly independent whenever $ n (5 n + 2) (5 n + 3) (5 n + 4) \neq  0$, vectors 1,2,3,5 are linearly independent when $ n (5 n + 2) (5 n + 4) (5 n + 8) = 0 \neq 0$, which are all simultaneously true for large enough $n$; however, vectors 1,2,4,5 are *linearly dependent* and vectors 1,3,4,5 are *linearly dependent*. Since say vectors 1,2,3,5 are not linearly dependent it is enough to veriify that the sets $\{1,4\},$ $\{2,4\},$  $\{3,4\},$ and $\{4,5\}$ do not lie on a line; i.e. linearly dependent. $\{1,4\},$ 
 are linearly independent when $n (95 n + 21) \neq  0$, $\{2,4\},$ 
 are linearly independent when $ 5 n (11 n + 5) + 4 \neq  0$, $\{3,4\},$ 
 are linearly independent when $n (161 n + 103) + 20  \neq  0$, and $\{3,4\},$ 
 are linearly independent when $n (125 n + 84) + 15  \neq  0$.

**Therefore they cannot lie on $m=4$ lines. Therefore the case for $c_i  \in \mathbb{N}$ is false. I have considered all 3 possible interpretations of your conjecture and they are all false.**

Comment: I get lost in the very beginning—you seem to define $s_i$ in terms of $s_i$.  Should it be defined instead in terms of $c_i$?

Comment: $s_i = 0$ if $c_i = \frac{1}{2}c_{i-1}$ and $s_i = 1$ if $c_i =3 c_{i-1} +1 $.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out I changed the $s_i$ in the definition to $c_i$.

Comment: It seems that you consider Collatz $m$-tuples $(c_0,\dots, c_{m-1})$ which are final, that is $c_{m-1}=1$, whereas in the question there is no this restriction. Also I don’t see how we can consider a general case $c_i \in \mathbb{Q}$, because non-integer rationals are neither even, nor odd, so I don’t see which or rules $n\to n/2$ or $n\to 3n+1$ should be applied to it.

Comment: To the sequence (x,0,0,1) we attach the sequence $(x,x/2,x/4, 3(x/2)+1)  $, that is definitely a well defined concept. I consider all possible interpretations. Keep reading; the Case where $c_0, c_1,...,c_m$ are integers without the restriction $c_m =1$ is the last case. I think that is the most meaningful case and it has a more involved proof.

Comment: Lol I mean $3(x/4)+1$ or else it's not "well-defined" ;)

Comment: I added an introduction clarifying the 3 different cases and a cleary marked header to each section. I hope that clarifies things. The point is I proved that the conjecture is false under any conceivable variation of the problem. Let me know if you are having trouble with anything else. Thanks! Take care!

Comment: Do you think the OP may have only meant *successive* tuples?  And therefore their question is a simple case of drawing a 2d plane through any two neighbouring pairs by abstracting away all predecessors, leaving the trivial case $(3x+1,x/2)$?

Comment: I believe the interpretation was tuples of arbitrary length $m$ of the form $(3x+1,(3x+1)/2,3(3x+1)/2+1,...)$ or $(x/2,x/4,3x/4+1,...)$ etc.. The claim is that all tuples of length $m$ can be found on $m$ lines. However, the claim is not true as you can see from my response, for the case $m=4$ (case#3), the 5 tuples $(n,n/2,n/4,n/8)$, $(n,n/2,n/4,3n/4+1)$, $(n,n/2,3n/2+1,1/2(3n/4+1))$, $(n,3n+1,1/2(3n+1),1/4(3n+1)) $, and $(n,3n+1,1/2(3n+1),3/2(3n+1)+1)$ form a counter example to this claim. However,  that did not seem to disuade the other users @AlexRavsky and OP from chasing their pipedream.

Comment: @PedroJuanSoto the OP has answered and indicated he only meant **successive** tuples are orthogonal. In my tentative view this gives the question the trivial answer that one can abstract away all but two neighbouring pairs by drawing a plane through them, leaving the trivial case $(3x+1,x/2)$ https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359302/a-possibly-easy-question-about-latent-geometry-in-collatz-sequences?noredirect=1#comment913031_359302 https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359302/a-possibly-easy-question-about-latent-geometry-in-collatz-sequences?noredirect=1#comment913093_359302